# Почему ctx.filter не работает?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

Я просо использую вот этот [код](https://github.com/HashLips/generative-art-node/blob/main/src/main.js)
И решил добавить фильтр
Я добавил его сюда

```
const image = await loadImage(`${_layer.location}${element.fileName}`);
  ctx.filter = 'contrast(1.4) sepia(1) drop-shadow(-9px 9px 3px #e81)';
  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    _layer.position.x,
    _layer.position.y,
    _layer.size.width,
    _layer.size.height
  );

  saveLayer(canvas, _edition);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работа фильтра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно, что к чему относится. Где ваши изображения? Бегемот откуда?

Comment: @Leonid   Из документаций